# Can I upgrade a Norco Yorkville for a 260 pound rider plus cargo?

Tags: parts, upgrades, heavy, clydesdale

Hello I have a 2017 Norco Yorkville. I was breaking rear spokes so bought a better rim with tougher spokes. Now my suspension seat post is wobbling.
What else can I upgrade on the bike for a 300 pound plus load? I could trade up to the next level bike but prefer to stay with this one.

[image: From Norco website.]

Aluminium 7005 frame, 21 speed (3x7) with rim-brakes and suspension seat post.  https://www.norco.com/bikes/city/hybrids/yorkville/yorkville/   With a MSRP of $369 USD its above a BSO, but still an entry-level model.

Comment: It really depends what parts are close to their limits.  Wheel has shown that by breaking spokes.

Comment: I've just added a stock photo of this model.  If this is not your bike please use edit.

Comment: Thanks Criggle,I am an older rider. This is the first new bike I have bought in fifty years.I thought the bike was better than an entry level model because I didn't know prices very well. Where I live there are a lot of potholes. I can't do the bunny hop either because of my back. I want this bike to last me ten years. Another sign certain parts are at their limits is my suspension seat post wobbles even though everything is tight. If I have to I will trade this one in on a better bike.

Comment: It should be a fairly decent bike -- not ideal for someone your weight, but not bad for the price.  32-spoke wheels are about as good as you can do anymore, short of getting them custom-built, and suspension posts will tend to go soft fairly rapidly.  I'd ride it until it starts having more serious problems, then buy something slightly more substantial.

Comment: I'd consider swapping out the suspension seatpost with a normal one.  But you'll loose the suspension function.   Your other option there is to put a bit more weight on the pedals (ie ride harder) to unweight and reduce the bum/saddle load.   That bike should last you a good 10 years without problem, provided you do the usual basic maintenance.

Comment: Replace the suspension post with a fixed post, as @Criggie notes. Then get a sprung saddle -- either a Brooks if you're rich or at least one with springs. Avoid the overcushioned ones sold at Walmart/bigbox stores. Too much cushioning is actually harder on the butt. However, springs are good.

Comment: @DanielRHicks you could easily get a decent 36 spoke back wheel for that bike. I paid the equivalent of around $100 for one a year or so ago after breaking my rim at a spoke hole.

Comment: @ChrisH - Yeah, about $100, and you can get one built for that.  While the 32 spoke wheel is around $25.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I think the issue is that while you can get a $25 32 spoke wheel, there's no point selling a 36 spoke wheel with the same quality components. So mine had spoke eyelets and a Deore hub, for example. That might well be what the OP needs, though a bit of an expensive upgrade given the purchase price of the bike

Answer (score 1):

One solution for getting the load off the bike is to tow it in a trailer.

This would be overkill if you're carting around a waterbottle and a pocket of keys, but if you're loading the bike with 20+ kilos (44+ pounds) of stuff then moving it to its own axle could help.

Downside, trailers aren't cheap, and they will slow you down while riding.